# How to apply CoreImage filters to a video file efficiently?

Tags: ios, video, filter, core-image

How to apply filters to a recorded video file ?

I've go through the document of CoreImage, there are demos of how to apply filters to a still image, but no pre-recorded video file. Although I knew a video is a batch of still images, I could apply that to a each frame of the video. But I still want to know an efficient way to do that

Any example(or instruments) of how to apply filter to a  video file?
Thank you very much! This problem tortures me a lot .

Comment: I know this is an old question, but this came up as a related question to a new one. In case you haven't found any answers, here's a link to an article written in Swift 2 - it also has a GitHub repository for the code: http://flexmonkey.blogspot.com/2015/07/applying-cifilters-to-live-camera-feed.html?view=magazine There's other articles on this site that may help too.

Comment: I had the same question (https://stackoverflow.com/q/39114863/2767207 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/39137099/2767207), and I was able to figure it out using `AVVideoCompositing` and `AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction`. The code I used [is now on Github](https://github.com/jojodmo/VideoFilterExporter). As [selaband](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4106196/selaband) said in their answer below, I used [Apple's Objective-C implementation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/CIFunHouse/Introduction/Intro.html) to figure out how to do it with Swift.