# Applying a CIFilter to a Video File and Saving it

Tags: ios, swift, cifilter, avasset

Is there any fast, lightweight-as-possible way to apply a `CIFilter` to a video? Before it's mentioned, I *have* looked at [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) - it looks like very powerful <s>magic</s> code, but it's really overkill for what I'm trying to do.

Essentially, I would like to

1. Take a video file, say stored at `/tmp/myVideoFile.mp4`
2. Apply a `CIFilter` to this video file
3. Save the video file to a different (or the same) location, say `/tmp/anotherVideoFile.mp4`

I've been able to apply a CIFilter to a video that's playing extremely easily and quickly using `AVPlayerItemVideoOutput`

```
let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: AVPlayerItem(asset: video))
let output = AVPlayerItemVideoOutput(pixelBufferAttributes: nil)
player.currentItem?.addOutput(self.output)
player.play()

let displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(self.displayLinkDidRefresh(_:)))
displayLink.addToRunLoop(NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop(), forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)

func displayLinkDidRefresh(link: CADisplayLink){
    let itemTime = output.itemTimeForHostTime(CACurrentMediaTime())
    if output.hasNewPixelBufferForItemTime(itemTime){
        if let pixelBuffer = output.copyPixelBufferForItemTime(itemTime, itemTimeForDisplay: nil){
            let image = CIImage(CVPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)
            // apply filters to image
            // display image
        }
    }
}
```

This works great, but I've been having <s>a lot</s> just the tiniest bit of trouble finding out how to apply a filter to an already saved video file. There is the option of basically just doing what I did above, using an `AVPlayer`, playing the video, and getting the pixel buffer from every frame as it is played but this won't work for video processing in the background. I don't think users would appreciate having to wait as long as their video is for the filter to be applied.

In way over-simplified code, I'm looking for something like this:

```
var newVideo = AVMutableAsset() // We'll just pretend like this is a thing

var originalVideo = AVAsset(url: NSURL(urlString: "/example/location.mp4"))
originalVideo.getAllFrames(){(pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer) -> Void in
    let image = CIImage(CVPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)
        .imageByApplyingFilter("Filter", withInputParameters: [:])

    newVideo.addFrame(image)
}

newVideo.exportTo(url: NSURL(urlString: "/this/isAnother/example.mp4"))
```

Is there any way fast (again, not involving GPUImage, and ideally working in iOS 7) way to apply a filter to a video file and then save it? For example this would take a saved video, load it into an `AVAsset`, apply a `CIFilter`, and then save the new video to a different location.

Comment: I was able to get this working, and the code [is now available on GitHub](https://github.com/jojodmo/VideoFilterExporter)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In iOS 9 / OS X 10.11 / tvOS, there's a convenience method for applying `CIFilter`s to video. It works on an `AVVideoComposition`, so you can use it both for playback and for file-to-file import/export. See [`AVVideoComposition.init(asset:applyingCIFiltersWithHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avvideocomposition/1389556-init) for the method docs.

There's an example [in Apple's Core Image Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_tasks/ci_tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH3-DontLinkElementID_8), too:

```
let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")!
let composition = AVVideoComposition(asset: asset, applyingCIFiltersWithHandler: { request in

    // Clamp to avoid blurring transparent pixels at the image edges
    let source = request.sourceImage.clampingToExtent()
    filter.setValue(source, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

    // Vary filter parameters based on video timing
    let seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(request.compositionTime)
    filter.setValue(seconds * 10.0, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)

    // Crop the blurred output to the bounds of the original image
    let output = filter.outputImage!.cropping(to: request.sourceImage.extent)

    // Provide the filter output to the composition
    request.finish(with: output, context: nil)
})
```

That part sets up the composition. After you've done that, you can either play it by assigning it to an `AVPlayer` or write it to a file with `AVAssetExportSession`. Since you're after the latter, here's an example of that:

```
let export = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: AVAssetExportPreset1920x1200)
export.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
export.outputURL = outURL
export.videoComposition = composition

export.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler(/*...*/)
```

There's a bit more about this [in the WWDC15 session on Core Image, starting around 20 minutes in](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-510/?time=1222).

---

If you want a solution that works on earlier OS, it's a bit more complicated.

> <sup>Aside: Think about how far back you really need to support. [As of August 15, 2016](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/), 87% of devices are on iOS 9.0 or later, and 97% are on 
>   iOS 8.0 or later. Going to a lot of effort to support a small slice of your potential customer base—and it'll get even smaller by the time you get your project done and ready to deploy—might not be worth the cost.</sup>

There are a couple of ways to go at this. Either way, you'll be getting `CVPixelBuffer`s representing source frames, [creating `CIImage`s from them](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coreimage/ciimage/1438072-init), applying filters, and [rendering out new `CVPixelBuffer`s](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coreimage/cicontext/1437835-render).

1. Use `AVAssetReader` and `AVAssetWriter` to read and write pixel buffers. There's examples for how to do this (the reading and writing part; you still need to do the filtering in between) in the [Export](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/05_Export.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH9-SW2) chapter of Apple's AVFoundation Programming Guide.
2. Use `AVVideoComposition` with a custom compositor class. Your custom compositor is given [`AVAsynchronousVideoCompositionRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avasynchronousvideocompositionrequest) objects that provide access to pixel buffers and a way for you to provide processed pixel buffers. Apple has a sample code project called [AVCustomEdit](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/AVCustomEdit/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013411-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) that shows how to do this (again, just the getting and returning sample buffers part; you'd want to process with Core Image instead of using their GL renderers).

Of those two, the `AVVideoComposition` route is more flexible, because you can use a composition both for playback and export.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've done a lot with `AVVideoComposition`, yet I can't seem to be able to get the [`startVideoCompositionRequest()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVVideoCompositing_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/AVVideoCompositing/startVideoCompositionRequest:) function, which gets a CVPixelBuffer, to work. It gets called, but doesn't have any track IDs (and therefore no pixel buffers), when I set `passthroughTrackID` on my `AVVideoCompositionInstruction` class. It doesn't, however, get called when I don't set the track id.

Comment: Do you have any idea what might be causing this? If it's more complicated than just that (which it probably is), I'll post another question asking about it - I just thought I would ask you here first incase it's something really obvious

Comment: Hard to say without seeing some (probably non-trivial) code, so probably better as its own question.

Comment: Is anyone else getting blurred results from this?

Comment: I exactly copy pasted this code, but the video came out completely black and without sound. Any thoughts? @rickster

Comment: A beautifully constructed summary.

Comment: Never tried this, but looks cool. Gonna try this out if this is faster.

Comment: hi @rickster please give me any suggestion regarding my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54652637/i-want-to-apply-cifilter-on-video-and-save-that-filter-applied-video-export-ta