# CIImage back to CMSampleBuffer

Tags: ios, swift, core-image, video-recording

I record video (.mp4 file) using `AVAssetWriter` with `CMSampleBuffer` data (from video, audio inputs).

While recording I want to process frames, I'm converting `CMSampleBuffer` to `CIImage` and processing it.

but how to update `CMSampleBuffer` with my new processed image buffer from `CIImage`?

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    if output == videoOutput {
       let imageBuffer: CVPixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)!
       let ciimage: CIImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: imageBuffer)
       ... // my code to process CIImage (for example add augmented reality)
       // but how to convert it back to CMSampleBuffer?
       // because AVAssetWriterInput to encode video/audio in file needs CMSampleBuffer
       ...
    } 
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to render your CIImage into a CVPixelBuffer, using CIContext's [`render(_:to:bounds:colorSpace:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cicontext/1437835-render) method.

Then you can create a CMSampleBuffer from the CVPixelBuffer using e.g. [`CMSampleBufferCreateReadyWithImageBuffer(_:_:_:_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremedia/1489745-cmsamplebuffercreatereadywithima)

You may need to use a pool of CVPixelBuffer for efficiency reasons, an example of this is shown in Apple's AVCamPhotoFilter sample code. In particular, see the [RosyCIRenderer class](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVCamPhotoFilter/Listings/AVCamPhotoFilter_RosyCIRenderer_swift.html).

Also see this answer which may help you [Applying a CIFilter to a Video File and Saving it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39114863/applying-a-cifilter-to-a-video-file-and-saving-it)

Comment: yes I found answer myself already (I already gave a link), this question can be closed - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49066195/what-is-the-best-way-to-record-a-video-with-augmented-reality and performance sucks that's why I asked different question about best way to add text/ better performance - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49066195/what-is-the-best-way-to-record-a-video-with-augmented-reality